# Updated Eclipse and my workspace is gone

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I had been using a pre built workspace with Minecraft forge and have successfully installed forge before. I have been using it for months now. After I updated eclipse, the workspace is gone even when I point eclipse to the correct folder. And when I say gone, I mean I cannot see any files. I tried reinstalling forge and eclipse with the latest versions to no avail. All the other problems like this one have SOMETHING in the hierarchy.

I did not get any errors on the reinstall to post. My other work spaces are imported just fine, it is only my forge work space that is not showing up. I tried to point eclipse to the project itself and ended up with a bunch of errors and the libraries where not imported. This is what you get when you run gradlew eclipse in debug because I am assuming that is where the error is. http://pastebin.com/0sFjxypB. I tired posting this to the Minecraft forge forum, but no one could help.

Comment: Did u try importing your workspace into eclipse ?

Comment: You can do it by selecting import > project

Comment: I did. I tried repointing it to the correct workspace folder and importing the project itself. The workspace showed up empty and when i tired to import the project into that same workspace, it said the workspaces overlapped and the project was open even though no files showed up. When i tried to import it into a different workspace folder, no errors came on the import but a bunch showed up in my code. The libraries necessary to run forge did not import over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this once too.

Just do a fresh forge install in a new directory, then copy over your src directory.
Also copy over relevant changes in build.gradle

That's usually the best way to solve this.

Also, good to know: Eclipse cannot handle directory changes of projects. it hardcodes the directory location in it's eclipse metadata. if the location changes eclipse turns dumb and can't find jack shit.
(for example upgrading to windows 10, and your user name changed from mdibbets to mdibb in the users directory)

Answer (score 0):

One big hint with Eclipse is always put the workspace in a different folder location to the Source. We tend to do C:\workspace\myProject  and the source in C:\dev\myProject